# Java wait - synchronized in/outside while loop

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I'm just working through the consumer/producer problem to get myself acquainted with concurrency issues in Java. My question is maybe adjacent to the C/P problem itself. In the code snippets below, if I user version 1 the program seems to run fine whilst with version 2 I seem to get a deadlock after a variable amount of time.

I'll only post the Producer class as there's no need for the Consumer one.

- buffer is where the Producer deposits its output
- I'm just adding Integers of 1 into it
- while(true) is to keep the thread running continuously

**My question is**: I know that in the Java API the structure for calling wait() is: synchronized -> while -> wait. But what happens in the situation: while -> synchronized -> wait? If during the wait(), the Consumer calls notifyAll() and the Producer wakes up again then wouldn't the code continue from where wait() was called and eventually it would hit the while(buffer.remainingCapacity() == 0)?

I've done digging around to see if this has been asked before but couldn't find anything specific to this.

**Version 1**

```
public class Producer extends Thread {
    ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> buffer = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    public Producer(ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized(buffer) {
                while (buffer.remainingCapacity() == 0) {
                    try {
                        buffer.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                synchronized (buffer) {
                    buffer.add(1);
                    System.out.println("Producer active with remaining capacity: " + buffer.remainingCapacity());
                    buffer.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Version 2**

```
public class Producer extends Thread {
    ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> buffer = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

    public Producer(ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            while (buffer.remainingCapacity() == 0) {
                synchronized (buffer) {
                    try {
                        buffer.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                synchronized (buffer) {
                    buffer.add(1);
                    System.out.println("Producer active with remaining capacity: " + buffer.remainingCapacity());
                    buffer.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just for the sake of it, this is another version code for the problem which appears to be working. I'm just putting it here in case it would be helpful for other people or if anyone can tell me whether it's wrong and why. Compared to the versions above this one has the wait and notifyAll methodes "flipped" in the code when it comes to their position.

```
while(true) {
            while(buffer.remainingCapacity() == 0){
                synchronized (buffer){
                    buffer.notifyAll();
                }
            }
            try {
                buffer.add(1);
                System.out.println("Producer active with remaining capacity: " + buffer.remainingCapacity());
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                synchronized (buffer){
                    try {
                        buffer.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't it clearly wrong to call `buffer.remainingCapacity` without being inside a `synchronized` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the correct way of using `ArrayBlockingQueue` or really any `BlockingQueue` for Producer/Consumer problems is shown in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) of that interface, slightly adjusted for your example:

Producer

```
    try {
        while (true) {
            queue.put(1);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // something want's us to stop.
    }
```

Consumer

```
    try {
        while (true) {
            Integer thing = queue.take();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // something want's us to stop.
    }
```

There is exactly 0 `synchronized`/`wait`/`notify` because that's what those queues provide built into `put` and `take`. You should in practice use those. Writing your own just leads to errors.
Since you use `synchronized`/`wait`/`notify` manually, you could have taken anything to serve as buffer. E.g. an `ArrayList`. Granted, there is no `remainingCapacity()` method on those, so a bound queue isn't a bad choice after all.

But there is another problem in your implementation beyond the deadlock: It will fail in case there is more than 1 producer or consumer: Your code has 2 synchronized blocks per iteration. What could happen now is:

- Queue has exactly 1 slot open.
- Producer 1, checks that there is space in the queue, leaves synchronized
- Producer 2, checks that there is space in the queue, leaves synchronized
- Producer 2, enters 2nd synchronized, puts something in, queue is now full, leaves
- Producer 1, enters 2nd synchronized, puts something.. arr - crash.

What you really need to synchronize as 1 big atomic operation is the whole check-then-wait-and-put thing. You would end up with roughly

```
    try {
        while (true) {
            // produce outside of synchronized
            Integer product = 1;

            // BEGIN put atomic
            synchronized (buffer) {
                while (buffer.remainingCapacity() == 0) {
                    buffer.wait();
                }
                buffer.add(product);
                buffer.notifyAll();
                System.out.println("Producer active with remaining capacity: "
                        + buffer.remainingCapacity());
            }
            // END put atomic

            // consumer should likewise consume the product outside
            // of the synchronized block
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The part between BEGIN and END is also roughly what the implementation of `put()` in `ArrayBlockingQueue` does.

PS: your "flipped" example is indeed wrong as well. Besides those 2 synchronized blocks:
Look at the CPU consumption of your program when you have a slow consumer: It will spike because the producer is actively stuck in a loop notifying. That's basically 100% CPU load for nothing.

Furthermore, using the `IllegalStateException` to detect that you shouldn't have added something, then retry is at least bad style and I'm not sure if there isn't another hidden deadlock when it comes to multiple producers or consumers.

And lastly, you're relying on the synchronization built into `buffer.add()` to make sure that you even get that exception. When writing your own p/c, never read or write a buffer outside of `synchronized`.

You may want to use a non-synchronized collection like an `ArrayList` to implement this after all, so errors in your code are not hidden by the synchronization of something else.

Comment: Thank you, the explanation is clear and detailed and answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

The thing to consider with synchronization is "what operation needs to be atomic?"  In your example, the check-then-wait must be atomic.  Otherwise, consider the following sequence of events:

- Thread1: Check performed and fails
- Thread2: Update buffer changing the result of the check
- Thread2: Notify called
- Thread1: Wait called

In this scenario, Thread1 misses the notification and blocks until another notification comes.  Putting the check inside the sync block eliminates that possibility as Thread2 cannot call notify until Thread1 calls wait.

Comment: I think I get it. In the Producer version 2 class the while(buffer.remainingCapacity() == 0) is evaluated, the buffer is full and then the JVM decides to give the Consumer thread a go and it evaluates its while(buffer.isEmpty()), sees it is false then goes ahead to "consume()" until the buffer is empty, then does notifyAll(), goes back to loop again through while(true), sees the buffer empty then calls wait() then the JVM switches to the Producer thread and calls buffer.wait() then nothing else happens.